# Sqlite on windows phone 8

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8

Recently I downloaded win8 phone sdk and started create my test application.
In the main project i have a System.Data.SQLite based classes and want to implement it in my windows phone app.

But System.Data.Sqlite package refuse to install with NuGet and says "Incompartible c# version" or something.

I have tried sqlite-wp80-winrt-3071500.vsix from http://www.sqlite.org/download.html, it installs ok but i even doesn't know how to refer the sqlite library? There is no such as ADO.Net adapter I suppose and I can't find exact library to refer in code.

In my test WP7 application I had implemented System.Data.Sqlite and it was working ok but what should I do with windows phone 8?

Please help me. May be it is a dumb question but I am stuck on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't mind using an ORM instead of an ADO.NET provider, give [sqlite-net-wp8](https://github.com/peterhuene/sqlite-net-wp8) a try (just created it today for something I was working on).

sqlite-net-wp8 is a simple C++/CX wrapper around some sqlite3.dll exports that sqlite-net depends on.  It allows sqlite-net to call into sqlite3.dll on Windows Phone 8 without having to use csharp-sqlite instead.

Follow the instructions in the README and see if it works for you.  Please let me know if you run into any bugs and pull requests are welcome :)

Comment: I just pushed an important bug fix where string columns weren't being bound to properly.  Please update your sqlite-net-wp8 source if you are still giving it a try.  Let me know if you run into any problems!

Comment: Peter.. I just found that today... I was coming back here to follow up... Awesome that you beat me to it :)  Great job.

Comment: Thanks, @DanielEgan.  Please let me know if you find any bugs.

Comment: @Peter, I just started trying to use sqlite-net with C#-SQLite but don't know, what should be the connection string? Uri will be good but I haven't see that option.

Comment: @gleb.kudr: sqlite-net uses a path to a file in the constructors for SQLiteConnection and SQLiteAsyncConnection.  That's all you should really need.  If you're developing for Windows Store or Windows Phone 8, you'll want a path under ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path.

Comment: @Peter Oh I was absolutely sure it is the same way as in wp7 but wp8 storage structure is different now i see it. Thank you for this answer.

Comment: @Peter thank you a lot with your solution. It is finally working fine for me. The last question. Does your implementation meets the Microsoft app store requirement?

Comment: @gleb.kudr: it should, as far as I know.  I'll be submitting to the store shortly, so if there are any problems, I'll correct it in the wrapper.

Comment: @Peter cold you tell me what is wrong with this:                              SQLiteAsyncConnection connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(this.Path); await connection.ExecuteAsync("PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF;"); Pragma statement is always throws me SQLite exception. No matter I use await or not, or doing var x= connection.ExecuteQsync... Statements without pragma are fine.

Comment: @gleb.kudr: Sorry, I"m not sure why that is throwing an exception.  Does the exception message hold any relevant information?

Comment: @Peter Here is the screenshot. It throws unhandled exception with the message "Row" http://clip2net.com/s/2FA7i while the ExecuteNonQuery.

Comment: It looks like it is returning a row and ExecuteNonQuery doesn't expect one.  Perhaps try ExecuteScalarAsync instead of ExecuteAsync?  It will at least return the first column in the row (I'm not sure what data your pragma statement is returning, though).