# SQLite in Windows Phone 8

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm trying to convert my WP 7.1 application to WP8. The target is still WP 7.1 but I'm attempting to debug on a WP8 device. I'm using [CSharp-SQLite](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/), but when I try to access the database and call `.Open` on the connection, I get an error: `A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll`

I remember developing for WP7.1 was a nightmare because of such exceptions. Is there a reliable way to use SQLite in WP8?

**EDIT:** I'm sharing this database between a desktop app, WP app and an iOS app, so I need access to the tables. I can't just let an ORM wrapper create the tables for me. Is there no way to just get access tp a DbDataReader?

Comment: Take a look at the links in this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474029/sqlite-on-both-windows-phone-7-1-and-windows-phone-8

Comment: Yes, check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855461/sqlite-on-windows-phone-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this problem after a couple of weeks of trying various suggestions by using the [Vici CoolStorage DLLs](http://viciproject.com/wiki/projects/coolstorage/home).